# geoserver wms layer drawing incomplet in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I have a wms layer from geoserver like the following :

```
wmslayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'poste:layer',
            'TILED': true,
            'STYLES': 'styleLayer'
        }
    }))
}); map.addLayer(wmslayer);
```

And the styleLayer in SLD is

```
<Rule>
  <Name>rule1</Name>
  <Title>Red Square</Title>
  <Abstract>A 6 pixel square with a red fill and no stroke</Abstract>
    <PointSymbolizer>
      <Graphic>
        <Mark>
          <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
          <Fill>
            <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
          </Fill>
        </Mark>
      <Size>
        <ogc:PropertyName>taille</ogc:PropertyName>                                   
      </Size>
    </Graphic>
  </PointSymbolizer>        
</Rule>
```

And the result is : (the probleme is that I dont know why the drawing is incomplet)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The symbols are cut at the tile boundaries. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87116/geoserver-cut-off-symbols-close-to-tile-edges for a similar question.

Comment: this issue is only done if I make size value from attribute. if I make size fix, il will be ok

Comment: An alternative is to use the `gutter` option (on `ol.source.TileWMS`). The docs provide information on that option: <https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/bf43816b66bceaabd7a1f1dc96a21baf9b9604ec/externs/olx.js#L4789>.